# Design of a pipeline that invokes a maximum number of requests per second

Tags: apache-beam

My goal is to create a pipeline that invokes a back-end (Cloud hosted) service a maximum number of times per second ... how can I achieve that?

Back story: Imagine a back-end service that is invoked with a single input and returns a single output.  This service has quotas associated with it that permit a maximum number of requests per second (let's say 10 requests per second).  Now imagine an unbounded source PCollection where I wish to transform the elements in the input by passing them through my back-end service.  I can envisage a ParDo invoking the back-end service once for each element in the input PCollection.  However, this doesn't perform any kind of flow control against the back-end.

I could imagine my DoFn logic testing the response from the back-end response and retrying till it succeeds but this doesn't feel right.  If I have 100 workers, then I seem to be burning a lot of resources and putting a load on the back-end.  What I think I want to do is throttle the calls to the back-end from the pipeline.

Comment: I believe there is some work being done on this, I will try to reach the author to post details. The closest that I see is DatastoreIO, which implemented [RampupThrottlingFn](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/datastore/RampupThrottlingFn.java) to provide some ramp-up flow control.

Answer (score 1):

Good Day, [kolban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1738915/kolban).  In addition to [Bruno Volpato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695821/bruno-volpato)'s helpful [RampupThrottlingFn](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/datastore/RampupThrottlingFn.java) example, I've seen a combination of the following.  Please do not hesitate at all to let me know how I can update the example with more clarity.

1. [PeriodicImpulse](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/PeriodicImpulse.html) - emits an [Instant](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/joda-time/joda-time/2.10.10/org/joda/time/Instant.html) at a fixed specified interval.
2. Fix the number of workers with the `maxNumWorkers` and `numWorkers` (Please see [Dataflow Pipeline Options](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/pipeline-options#resource_utilization)), if using the [Dataflow runner](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs).
3. [Beam Metrics API](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/metrics/Counter.html) to monitor the actual resource request count over time and set alerts.  When using Dataflow, the Beam Metrics API automatically connects to [Cloud Monitoring as Custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-cloud-monitoring#custom_metrics)

The following shows abbreviated code starting from the whole pipeline followed by some details as needed to provide clarity.  It assumes a target of `10` workers, using Dataflow with the arguments `--maxNumWorkers=10` and `--numWorkers=10` and a goal to limit the resource requests among all workers to `10 requests per second`.  This translates to `1 request per second per worker`.

### PeriodicImpulse limits the Request creation to 1 per second

```java
public class MyPipeline {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(/* Usually with options */);
        PCollection<Response> responses = pipeline.apply(
            "PeriodicImpulse",
            PeriodicImpulse
                .create()
                .withInterval(Duration.standardSeconds(1L))
        ).apply(
            "Build Requests",
            ParDo.of(new RequestFn())
        )
        .apply(ResourceTransform.create());
    }
}
```

### RequestFn DoFn emits Requests per Instant emitted from PeriodicImpulse

```java
class RequestFn extends DoFn<Instant, Request> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void process(@Element Instant instant, OutputReceiver<Request> receiver) {
        receiver.output(
            Request.builder().build()
        );
    }
}
```

### ResourceTransform transforms Requests to Responses, incrementing a Counter

```java
class ResourceTransform extends PTransform<PCollection<Request>, PCollection<Response>> {

    static ResourceTransform create() {
        return new ResourceTransform();
    }

    public PCollection<Response> expand(PCollection<Request> input) {
        return ParDo.of("Consume Resource", new ResourceFn());
    }
}

class ResourceFn extends DoFn<Request, Response> {

    private Counter counter = Metrics.counter(ResourceFn.class, "some:resource");

    private transient ResourceClient client = null;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        client = new ResourceClient();
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void process(@Element Request request, OutputReceiver<> receiver) 
    {
        counter.inc(); // Increment the counter.
        // not showing error handling
        Response response = client.execute(request);
        receiver.output(response);
    }
}
```

### Request and Response classes

(*Aside: consider [creating a Schema](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#creating-schemas) for the request input and response output classes. Example below uses [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/main/value/userguide/index.md) and [AutoValueSchema](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/AutoValueSchema.html)*)

```java
@DefaultSchema(AutoValueSchema.class)
@AutoValue
abstract class Request {

    /* abstract Getters. */

    abstract String getId();

    @AutoValue.Builder
    static abstract class Builder {

        /* abstract Setters. */

        abstract Builder setId(String value);

        abstract Request build();
    }
}

@DefaultSchema(AutoValueSchema.class)
@AutoValue
abstract class Response {

    /* abstract Getters. */

    abstract String getId();

    @AutoValue.Builder
    static abstract class Builder {

        /* abstract Setters. */

        abstract Builder setId(String value);

        abstract Response build();
    }
}
```